# NginX redirect /service to /service/

Tags: nginx, redirect, subdirectory, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have two servicesr accessible via NginX. The web server configuration looks like this:

```
location /service1/ {
    # process php files
}

location /service2/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999/;
}
```

However, if one clicks on https://example.com/service1 (or 2) he gets a 404 error. There is no folder called "service1" (or 2) in the website root.

I would like links to "https://example.com/service1" to point to "https://example.com/service1/" (with trailing slash), possibly without specyfing a redirect for every service I have, i.e

```
location = /service1 {
    return 301 https://$host/service1/;
}

location /service1/ {
    # process php files
}

location = /service2 {
    return 301 https://$host/service2/;
}

location /service2/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999/;
}
```

I have already tried `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`, but it seems to only work for real files and folders in the website root, no "virtual" subdirectories.

I am avoiding configurations like `location /service { ... }` because they seem more vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `location =` blocks you need to generate an internal redirect to `$uri/`. You can achieve this using `try_files` or `rewrite...last`.

For example:

```
location = /service1 {
    try_files nonexistent $uri/$is_args$args;
}
```

Notice that the internal redirection must be the **last** parameter. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Or:

```
location = /service1 {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1/ last;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Any way to make them work for service2 and eventual new services, without entering their names manually?

Comment: Can you write a regular expression that matches any service name? Are your services literally "service" followed by a digit? In either case, yes it's easy.